# Amplify logged in users cannot access S3 files using the Auth_Role

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a small question regarding Cognito authentication and S3. I tried to connect external S3 and Cognito instances to Amplify (Not managed by Amplify, I created manually). In the system, we can upload files to the S3 bucket and view them. I use Amplify JS's Storage class to do all this. The thing that got me confused is that when I give S3 permissions to the Cognito `Auth_Role`, my users cannot upload or view any files even-though they are logged into the system. When I give permission to the `Unauth_Role`, it works. Any idea why?